# Unity - instantiate origin object not accessable after cloneing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clone, instantiation

I cloned an array full of objects successfully. However, after trying to alter the objects in the origin arrays, I noticed that I cannot access those objects, and I don't know why. You can see the code below.

```
public Transform[,] vertricalArray;     // origin array
public Transform[,] horizontalArray;    // origin array
public Transform[,] boxes;              // origin array
public Transform[,] sim_Box;            // array in which the cloned objects are stored in
public Transform[,] sim_Vertical;       // array in which the cloned objects are stored in
public Transform[,] sim_Horizontal;     // array in which the cloned objects are stored in

for (int y = 0; y <= 3; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
    {
        if (x != 3 && y != 3)
        {
            Debug.Log("COPY OF BOX");
            sim_Box[x, y] = Instantiate(boxes[x, y], pos, transform.rotation) as Transform;
            if(sim_Box[x,y] != null)
            {
                sim_Box[x, y].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            }
        }   
        if (y != 3)
        {
            Debug.Log("COPY OF VERTICAL");
            sim_Vertical[x, y] = Instantiate(vertricalArray[x, y], pos, transform.rotation) as Transform;
            if(sim_Vertical[x,y] != null)
            {
                sim_Vertical[x, y].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            }
        }
        if (x != 3)
        {
            Debug.Log("COPY OF HORIZONTAL");
            sim_Horizontal[x, y] = Instantiate(horizontalArray[x, y], pos, transform.rotation) as Transform;
            if(sim_Horizontal[x,y] != null)
            {
                sim_Horizontal[x, y].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why cannot I alter the objects in the vertricalArray, horizontalArray, or boxes array?

Comment: You can try sim_Box[x, y].SetActive(false);

Comment: How are you sure that you have cloned the Transforms successfully? How are you trying to alter them exactly? I assume that this whole snippet is inside of a method. Do you receive any error messages when you run this code?

Comment: Hey @Hilse thanks for your feedback, i checked the simulation array for the objects inside. Also i can see them visually :) I tried to set the objects from the origin array inactive, but this is not working. I dont get any errors.

thanks

Comment: Again, how are you trying to access the originals *after* instantiating the simulated copies?

Comment: Hey @Draco18s i tried to acces the objects from the oringin arrays like this:   vertricalArray[1, 1].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
and
vertricalArray[1, 1].gameObject.SetActive(false);
both ways did not work after i cloned the objects into the new array..they worked before tough.

Comment: Define "didn't work."

Comment: @Draco18s nothing happens and the objects in the origin array stay the same as before ( when initilizing). I safe the the objects into the origin array, clone the arrays and when i set the objects from the origin array inactive via objec.SetActive(false); nothing happens and they are still active